# Why is “No new release found”?

Tags: upgrade, vps, do-release-upgrade, lsb-release

When I log in via SSH to my VPS (OpenVZ), I see:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 15.04 (GNU/Linux 2.6.32-042stab106.4 x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  System information as (...)

New release '15.04' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

#cat /etc/lsb-release (I want to check current version)

DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=15.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=vivid
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 15.04"

#do-release-upgrade (I'm upgrading)
Checking for a new ubuntu release
No new release found
```

If I have Ubuntu 15.04, why I see *New release '15.04' available.*?

Why *do-release-upgrade* return *No new release found*?

Why I see *New release avaiable*?

Previous version of Ubuntu: 14.10.

Comment: How are you running 2.6 kernel? Those haven't been around for *years*.

Comment: I have server on ovh.com. When I bought VPS, I selected system to install Ubuntu 14.10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `/etc/update-motd.d/91-release-upgrade`

Which calls `/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd`

This file then checks `/var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available`

If it exists it displays the `motd`, if not it will call `/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release`.

`check-new-release` gives the right result, but the file was not removed for some reason.

If you remove the file it will no longer display the `motd` and check for updates.

`sudo rm /var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available`

Comment: I don't understand, why it isn't removed, but now it's okay. Thanks!